# Entity Activity pointer - created by SYSTEM user access thru odbc driver

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9

How to determine the right REAL system user which record in this entity belongs to?

eg: task created by SYSTEM user, but I need to know the real user. (record owner is not a way when owning user can be changed when he leaves the company)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how that task is being really created. If I remember correctly, SYSTEM user is captured when entity records are created by portal user, Workflow/Plugin running on context, and some other scenarios.

Sometimes, ETL integration also does that, in those cases probably you have to check the `createdonbehalfby` column as well for accuracy.